# Deleting Card from RecyclerView and re-add it again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-viewholder, android-snackbar

I'm struggling to implement the funtionality to delete an entry of a recyclerview and re-add it again, if the user decided otherwise. For that I'm showing a `Snackbar` with an undo action.

So the flow should be: The user sees a list of `Cards` which each show some values and an delete button. If the user presses the delete button, the card is deleted and a `Snackbar`is shown. If the user clicks undo on the `Snackbar` the `Card` should be re-added to the `RecyclerView`. Only if the `Snackbar` disappears by timeout, the respective entry should also be deleted from `SQLite` database.

I'm populating the `TextViews` of the respective `Cards` and set the `OnClickListener` of the delete button in `onBindViewHolder`.

My class `CardApater` extending `RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder>` looks like the follwing:

```
private List<CardEntry> cards;

public CardAdapter(List<CardEntry> cards) {
    this.cards = cards;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cards.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, int i) {
    final CardEntry card = cards.get(i);

    cardViewHolder.tvDate.setText(card.date);
    cardViewHolder.tvValue1.setText(card.value1);
    cardViewHolder.tvValue2.setText(card.value2);
    cardViewHolder.tvValue3.setText(card.value3);

    cardViewHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            cards.remove(cardViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            notifyDataSetChanged();


            Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snack.setAction("Undo", this);
            snack.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

            snack.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                    super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                    switch (event) {
                        case DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION:
                            cards.add(card);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        case DISMISS_EVENT_TIMEOUT:
                            MainActivity.datasource.deleteSQLiteEntry(card.id);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            snack.show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.cardview, viewGroup, false);

    return new CardViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tvDate;
    protected TextView tvValue1;
    protected TextView tvValue2;
    protected TextView tvValue3;
    protected ImageView deleteButton;

    public CardViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvDate =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        tvValue1 = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.value1);
        tvValue2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value2);
        tvValue3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value3);
        deleteButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    }
}
```

Deleting the card works, but when re-adding the CardEntry to the list, the app crashes with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1` at the line `cards.remove(cardViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());` in the `onClick` method.

Any suggestions on that or why `onClick` is called at all when adding a new entry are appreciated.

Comment: This might be because of recycling. The adapter position of the removed card, currently points to nothing. You should keep the position out of the scope of the onBindViewHolder and use that one to re-add it

Comment: got it! thank you for the hint

Comment: Should i make it an answer that you will accept?

Comment: if you want to, then sure :)

Comment: Ok i am making it an answer so if someone else has the same problem can find it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of recycling. The adapter position of the removed card, currently points to nothing. You should keep the position out of the scope of the onBindViewHolder and use that one to re-add it.