# Android - onClickListener not working for ImageButton in CardView

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, cardview, android-imagebutton

I have searched StackOverflow for similar questions and I have followed the instructions described there but I'm still not being able to make my onClickListener fire for my image button. Can someone help me?

I explain my problem in detail.

Here is my xml for the CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_description"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/workout_start_action"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_workout" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/workout_delete_imgButton"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="FavButtonDesc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.example.workouttimer.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.workouttimer.R
import com.example.workouttimer.model.Workout


class WorkoutItemAdapter(private val context: Context,
                         private val dataset: List<Workout>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkoutItemAdapter.WorkoutItemViewHolder>() {

    class WorkoutItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_title)
        val descriptionTextView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_description)
        val imgDeleteButton = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.workout_delete_imgButton)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WorkoutItemViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.workout_list_item, parent, false)

        return WorkoutItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataset.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WorkoutItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.textView.text = item.workoutName
        holder.descriptionTextView.text = item.workoutDescription

        holder.imgDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            /*fun onClick(v: View) {
                Toast.makeText(v.context, "BORRADO!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            }*/

            fun onClick(position: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "BORRADO!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change **view.findViewById<ImageView>** to **view.findViewById<ImageButton>**

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's not fireing? I'm asking because you forgot to call `show()` on your toast. So in your on click try to log the event, or call `show()` on your toast like this:

```kotlin
Toast.makeText(context, "BORRADO!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

#### The real problem

So the code below is an example of [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions)

```kotlin
// What you did
View.OnClickListener { // This is where the SAM conversion happens
    fun onClick(position: Int) { // This is a local function defined inside your lambda
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "BORRADO!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }
}

// What you should've done
View.OnClickListener { // This is where the SAM conversion happens
    Toast.makeText(this.context, "BORRADO!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Because `View.OnClickListener` has only a single abstract method, by using SAM conversion, you don't have to specify which method you're overriding

Edit: in Kotlin you can't override a method without the `override` keyword

Comment: Well, it is hitting a breakpoint in "onClick" but looks like it is not entering the function to Toast line. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything remarkable. May be onClick function has wrong parameters or something?

Comment: Yes Patrik THANK YOU, that was the real problem (and I understand it), now it works, but what I don't understand is the syntax provided here (in which I based my code) (function inside function): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404324/how-to-delete-or-remove-cardview-from-recyclerview-android-studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497691/deleting-card-from-recyclerview-and-re-add-it-again

Comment: Cool could you accept my answer? I'm collecting hats :D

Comment: Yes, sure, but I must figure out, how (I'm new)

Comment: @Clandes this is how you accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Clandes The code you've linked is in java, if you want something similar in kotlin use object expressions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm having a hard time learning Android. It's too different from all the languages I know.